# Label disappears on GridLayout in Vaadin

Tags: java, label, vaadin, grid-layout, gridlayoutmanager

When I add a [`Label`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Label.html) to my [`GridLayout`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/GridLayout.html) in my [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home) 7 app, it fails to appear. I pass the Label to the [`addComponent`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/GridLayout.html#addComponent(com.vaadin.ui.Component)) method. This works in other [`Layout`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Layout.html) implementations, but not GridLayout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Set Width To Undefined

Adding a Label to a GridLayout is a special and annoying case. [Discussed](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/346621) in the forums. Technically a “feature”, not a bug.

A Label has its width set by default to 100%. Inside a GridLayout, the Label needs to be of "undefined" width.

This line will fix your problem:

```
myLabel.setSizeUndefined();
```

### Helper Method

I make frequent use of GridLayout to create professional and attractive layouts in Vaadin. This annoyance with Label in a GridLayout drives me batty, so I created this convenience method.

```
static public Label makeLabelSizeUndefined ( String caption )
{
    Label label = new Label( caption );
    label.setSizeUndefined();
    return label;
}
```

Example usage:

```
Label phoneLabel = WidgetHelper.makeLabelSizeUndefined( "Phone Number : " );
```